# OpenCV Video capture using keyboard to start/stop

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I have a running script capable of starting/stopping a video stream using 2 different keys;

- Program runs and shows the live stream.
- When `ESC` is hit, the program exits.
- When `SPACE` is hit, the video stream is captured.

However, when a video is captured it stores all the stream from the beginning of script execution.

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    output = cv2.VideoWriter('CAPTURE.avi', codec, 30, (640, 480))

    while True:
        ret, frame_temp = capture.read()
        cv2.imshow('FRAME', frame_temp)
        key=cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key%256 == 27:
            break
        elif key%256 == 32:
            output.write(frame_temp)

    capture.release()
    output.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

So, instead when the program runs I would like;

- Program runs and shows the live stream.
- Begin recording the stream when `SPACE` is hit and stop the recording when `SPACE` is hit once more.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extra variable to figure out if you are recording. I made a variable called `recording_flag`

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')

recording_flag = False

while True:
    ret, frame_temp = capture.read()
    cv2.imshow('FRAME', frame_temp)
    key=cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key%256 == 27:
        break
    elif key%256 == 32:
        if recording_flag == False:
            # we are transitioning from not recording to recording
            output = cv2.VideoWriter('CAPTURE.avi', codec, 30, (640, 480))
            recording_flag = True
        else:
            # transitioning from recording to not recording
            recording_flag = False

    if recording_flag:
        output.write(frame_temp)

capture.release()
output.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you for input. What this script does in fact is that the recording indeed begins after `SPACE` is hit and stops recording when I hit `ESC`. However, I would like to stop after pressing `SPACE` for second time.

Comment: My mistake. I needed an else statement to make `recording_flag` go to `False` when space bar is pressed again. See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

This line `while True:` isn't exactly ideal for what you're trying to do. I would recommend you define a function to do the recording and have it recursively call itself if the user stops recording via the space key. The top of your script would still start the same:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
output = cv2.VideoWriter('CAPTURE.avi', codec, 30, (640, 480))
```

Next you would define your function, it starts by waiting (forever) for a key to be pressed. Once a key is pressed if it is escape (27) it exits the function and cleans up, if it is space (32) it sets a boolean flag that starts recording (while loop). If neither escape or space is pressed it calls itself and starts the process over. Inside the while loop it checks if a key is pressed if so it checks if it is escape (27) or space (32). If either it hit it either exits the function (escape) or haults recording by calling itself which starts the process all over again (space).

```
def wait_then_capture():
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if key%256 == 27:
        return
    elif key%256 == 32:
        record = True
    else:
        wait_then_capture()
    while record == True:
        ret, frame_temp = capture.read()
        cv2.imshow('FRAME', frame_temp)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key%256 == 27:
            return
        elif key%256 == 32:
            break
        output.write(frame)
    wait_then_capture()
```

We then call our new function and end the script with the same cleanup you already have

```
wait_then_capture()

capture.release()
output.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Your finished script would look like this

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
output = cv2.VideoWriter('CAPTURE.avi', codec, 30, (640, 480))

def wait_then_capture():
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if key%256 == 27:
        return
    elif key%256 == 32:
        record = True
    else:
        wait_then_capture()
    while record == True:
        ret, frame_temp = capture.read()
        cv2.imshow('FRAME', frame_temp)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key%256 == 27:
            return
        elif key%256 == 32:
            break
        output.write(frame)
    wait_then_capture()

wait_then_capture()

capture.release()
output.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks @Source Code. The code has errors.
I get a `SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop` for the first break statement inside the wait_then_capture() function.

Comment: @tur360 - whoops I'll correct, it's supposed to be return. I don't have access to my environment while writing it.

Comment: I already tried that too. I get RuntimeError. Also the `wait_then_capture()` function is defined in two different ways in your explanation. So I tried all combinations no progress unfortunately.